# Android ORMLite DbHelper onCreate() not called even after uninstall

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm getting this error when I run my app for the first time after re-install:
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table

(This error happens when my app tries to read from the database)

For some reason the onCreate() method in DBHelper is not getting called and therefore the tables are not getting created. I followed the advice from other question and tried calling getWritableDatabase(), also tried a create() call to insert data in some table, but still no luck: onCreate is never called.

I got it to work however by changing the DATABASE_VERSION value to 2. But that doesn't make sense since this is a brand new installation after uninstall.
Also I found that before the SQL read error the database got created but it has only 1 table "android_metadata" (not created by me).
I'm posting some code here for reference

```html
 
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "RoutePlanner.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Dao<Trip, Integer> tripDAO = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Trip, Integer> tripRunTimeDAO = null;
     ...
}

@Override
    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        return super.getWritableDatabase();
}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION,    R.raw.ormlite_config);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource source) {

        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName(), "onCreate");
            TableUtils.createTable(source, Trip.class);
            ...
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName(), "Error creating db", ex);
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);

        }
}
```

Comment: OK, I found the problem, hope this explanations helps others on what NOT to do.   The issue was that I had a separate calendar module which I wanted to access my Database. To make things 'simpler' I created a separate DatabaseHelper on that module to access the same SQLite databse as my main module.  The existance of the 2nd DatabaseHelper was causing all my issues. Solutions are either join the 2 modules into one, or use a Database Service Provider

Comment: You should make this an answer to your own question if you would think it would help others, or you should remove this question.

Comment: Done. I'm new here, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the problem, hope this explanations helps others on what NOT to do. The issue was that I had a separate calendar module which I wanted to access my Database. To make things 'simpler' I created a separate DatabaseHelper on that module to access the same SQLite databse as my main module. The existance of the 2nd DatabaseHelper was causing all my issues. Solutions are either join the 2 modules into one, or use a Database Service Provider